# Filter deeply nested array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, projection

I have a requirement to filter a mongo collection with deeply nested array data. The document has 3 levels of nesting. Below is the sample document. The requirement is to filter the data with "status" as "verified" and also filter "array1" and "array2" based on condition and only return record which has matching data.

```
To summarise the filter params,
"status":"verified",
"name": "john",
"city": "mexico"
```

```
[
  {
    "_id": "111",
    "array1": [
      {
        "name": "john",
        "array2": [
          {
            "city": "mexico",
            "array3": [
              {
                "address": "address1",
                "status": "verified"
              },
              {
                "address": "address2",
                "status": "unverified"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "112",
    "array1": [
      {
        "name": "john",
        "array2": [
          {
            "city": "mexico",
            "array3": [
              {
                "address": "address1",
                "status": "unverified"
              },
              {
                "address": "address2",
                "status": "unverified"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expected output is as below,

```
{
  "_id": "111",
  "array1": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "array2": [
        {
          "city": "mexico",
          "array3": [
            {
              "address": "address1",
              "status": "verified"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you also include your expected output pls?

Comment: Is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/07ciRYtIDui) what are you looking for?. Otherwise please add expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it using nested `$filter` and `$map`, as you'll see the syntax is not very clean due to the schema being complex to work with.

Without knowing your product I recommend you revisit it, it might be worth to restructure depending on your common access patterns.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "array1.array2.array3.status": "verified"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      array1: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$array1",
              as: "mapone",
              in: {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$mapone",
                  {
                    array2: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: {
                          $map: {
                            input: "$$mapone.array2",
                            as: "maptwo",
                            in: {
                              "$mergeObjects": [
                                "$$maptwo",
                                {
                                  array3: {
                                    $filter: {
                                      input: "$$maptwo.array3",
                                      as: "three",
                                      cond: {
                                        $eq: [
                                          "$$three.status",
                                          "verified"
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        as: "filtertwo",
                        cond: {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              $gt: [
                                {
                                  $size: [
                                    "$$filtertwo.array3"
                                  ]
                                },
                                0
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              $eq: [
                                "$$filtertwo.city",
                                "mexico"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "filterone",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  {
                    $size: [
                      "$$filterone.array2"
                    ]
                  },
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$filterone.name",
                  "john"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6nX7Qf_vg2E)

Comment: Thank you. The results are as expected with the condition. Can you also help me implement filters for array1 and array2 with this aggregation? Like how can I filter "array1.name" or "array2.city"

Comment: Sure, can you edit your question to include these specifications?

Comment: I edited my answer, you just had to update the filter condition for each of the arrays.